# How to View Code (for Scraping) of Interactive Graph with Hover

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I would like to scrape an interactive plot that displays different information based on where the pointer is hovering. This website is what I am interested in: https://www.pelotoncycle.com/workout/c52db950f5ec4fde85cb3997c52db8db

For each line, I would like to scrape the information that appears in the box when one hovers over different segments of the line. For example, for the red line, starting at the left and going right, I would like to scrape:

```
0.13  power 70.1
0.58  power 74.9
1     power 94.8
and so on, repeating for each line
```

I have used python+Selenium to scrape dynamically-loading websites in the past, but am not sure how to handle this particular issue. I have tried, but have been unsuccessful in finding where in the code this information is contained. It is not in the page source HTML. I also can't find it using Firefox+Firebug or Chrome Canary when I use their inspect elements feature. The closest I can get when trying to find the relevant code is something like this:

```
<circle cx="213.69063545150502" cy="161.03099999999998" r="6.5" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="0.05" fill-opacity="1" fill="none">
```

Unfortunately, this appears to refer to the circle on the line and not on the actual information contained in the hovering box.

Any suggestion on what I should try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that another element containing the hover is overlayed on the chart for each point. The good news is that for each hover, a single CSS selector can be created. The hover appears in the ending `<g>` tag of the performance chart and the data can be gathered by getting all the points you need the information for, hovering on them each one by one, and using the following CSS Selector to gather the information.

```
g>text[text-anchor='start'][font-weight=bold]
```

Yes, it is a slow process but it works. If you want, you can also use JavaScript to get the data you need, but that would require diving deeper into the JS code of the website.

Comment: Thank you, @sagarwadhwa1. How did you see the code that enabled you to write down the CSS selector? And what process did you use that enabled you to figure my question out?

Comment: I had to automate the same chart some time back in another application. It took a lot of effort to find the elements corresponding to the hover in the HTML code but after that, it was easy. Click on the HTML code in inspect element window and use mouse to hover over the chart some time back.

Comment: I can't seem to get it because when the code changes from when I hover over because I have to move the mouse to select the proper code.

Comment: Yes, it can be a bit tricky. You'll have to open the dev tools in a separate window and then keeping it in focus, use the mouse to just hover over the data points. Then, using keyboard arrow keys, navigate and find the element of the hover.